# Flask MYSQL Commands out of sync

Tags: python, mysql, flask, axios

I have a react Frontend that is using Axios calls to make use of a Flask Backend which itself accesses a MySQL database. My endpoints work when tested singularly, but when I try to load my app my Backend hits this following error:"mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2014 (HY000): Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"

Below is a portion of my python code concerned with connecting with the database

```
import mysql.connector


conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",
                               user='user1',
                               password='Password',
                               database='pod1out',
                               auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')

def get_episodes_for_user(user_id):
    db_cursor = conn.cursor()
    statement = "select * from Episode inner join Episode_User_Relationship EUR on Episode.ID" \
                " = EUR.episode_id where user_id = %s;"
    db_cursor.execute(statement, (user_id,) )
    db_result = db_cursor.fetchall()
    db_cursor.close()
    return db_result

def get_friends_for_user(user_id):
    db_cursor = conn.cursor()
    statement = "select * from User join Friend_Relationship on user2_ID = User.id where user1_ID = %s;"
    db_cursor.execute(statement, (user_id,))
    db_result = db_cursor.fetchall()
    db_cursor.close()
    return db_result
```

What steps do I need to take to make sure that the database is not being accessed at the same time by two statements? Is this done in the methods shown above, the Flask Endpoint themselves, or the Frontend Axios methods?

Comment: **WARNING**: `format` and SQL statements should never really touch. Use the placeholder values and send in a tuple, like `execute("SELECT * FROM ... WHERE user_id=%s", (user_id,))`

Comment: OK thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Ok so I have changed that and now I have more problems. I am getting a "ValueError: Could not process parameters" for every single statement

Comment: It's worth updating with the newer iteration of your code for clarity.

Comment: Sure I have done that now

Comment: Note the strange tuple syntax must be used: `(user_id,)` with that comma sitting there doing nothing but ensuring it's a tuple. Python likes it that way. In cases with one value it looks kind of dumb but you get used to it. In other cases you can do `(a,b)` and it's fine. You just need at least one comma for it to be a tuple.

Comment: Ok great I am learning a lot here. Now pmy program is crashing with: "free(): double free detected in tcache 2

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)"

Comment: Well, one problem solved, a new mystery emerges!

Comment: I think I might just need to reset my pc cause it looks like I am running out of memory or something

Comment: Could be. A double `free()` could also be a bug somewhere in a compiled Python extension. Worth closing this out with a self-answer with what you learned and opening a new question with that problem, but do provide more detail about that crash and how to reproduce it.

Comment: Actually I solved that problem by restarting my pc... the old error stands, so I am going to leave this open!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the problem was that I was using the same connection for all the different calls, only creating it once at the top. So I edited it to create the connection seperately within each function instead.

```
def get_audio_for_episode(episode_id):
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",
                                   user='user1',
                                   password='Password',
                                   database='pod1out',
                                   auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')
    db_cursor = conn.cursor()
    statement = "select * from Episode where id = %s}"
    db_cursor.execute(statement, (episode_id,))
    db_result = db_cursor.fetchone()
    db_cursor.close()
    return db_result

def get_friends_for_user(user_id):
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",
                                   user='user1',
                                   password='Password',
                                   database='pod1out',
                                   auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')
    db_cursor = conn.cursor()
    statement = "select * from User join Friend_Relationship on user2_ID = User.id where user1_ID = %s;"
    db_cursor.execute(statement, (user_id,))
    db_result = db_cursor.fetchall()
    db_cursor.close()
    return db_result
```